# PySide Import Error on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: pyside

$python

Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Oct  1 2012, 22:04:36)

[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2

> > > import PySide
> > >
> > > PySide.**version**

'1.1.2'

> > > import PySide.QtCore

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

ImportError: libpyside-python2.6.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: $ ls /usr/lib$ ls /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PySide-1.1.2-py2.6.egg/PySide/libpyside-python2.6.so.1.1
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PySide-1.1.2-py2.6.egg/PySide/libpyside-python2.6.so.1.1

Comment: Yes, it is there, but the error still occurs.

Comment: What should I do to resolve it

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following to .bashrc helped.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PySide-1.1.2-py2.6.egg/PySide
```

It still didn't work in Eclipse; for that, I added `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as an environment variable.